# Threshold energy of Ti-48 inverse beta decay

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, neutrinos, nuclear-engineering

Goal: Use anti neutrinos to convert Ti-48 to Ca-48 using inverse beta decay (IBD). The resulting Ca-48 should have the same half-life as natural Ca-48.

Question: What is the threshold energy for the anti neutrino? In other words, what is the minimum energy to have IBD occur for the 48Ti --> 48Ca reaction?

If it helps any bit, the Q value for the neutrinoless double-beta decay of Ca-48 into Ti-48 is 4.37 MeV.

Comment: A more pressing question may well be cross-section. Experimental IBD rates for reactor energies are measure in events per day per *ton* of active detector. At beam energies the cross-sections are higher, but still very small. Getting two events on the same nucleus is a vanishingly rare occurrence.

Comment: While it would be nice, I am only interested in the threshold energy and Q-value. Cross section would be nice, but is not needed at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: the answer for the energy is  here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay   1.806Mev

Comment: @annav That's the value for free protons (i.e. hydrogen); it will be a little different in a nuclear context, though I imagine the scale remains the "a few MeV" in all but the most extreme cases.

Comment: @dmckee  yes, but the same method shown for protons may be used if one menages to estimate an average mass for a bound nucleon.

Comment: @Anna v would this mean that the Ti-48 would require a mere 1.806 MeV (the threshold energy mentioned in the wikipedia link) to become Ca-48? This seems a bit strange, since the Ca-48 emits around 4.37 MeV before it becomes Ti-48.

Comment: you have to take into account the effective mass of the average nucleon, which is less when talking of large nuclei, (dmckee noted this in his comments above)

Comment: @Anna v That resolves my confusion, I knew it sounded off. I take it then that the anti neutrino energy should be greater than or equal to 4.37 MeV (the Q value of Ca-48 --> Ti-48)?

Comment: Energy is always conserved, so if that is the value , that is what is needed.